# Odd coefficient in $M\in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{Z})$ satisfies $n\le m\le n²-n+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $M\in \mathcal{GL}_n(\Bbb{Z})$ I would like to prove that all odd coefficient of $M$ satisfies $n\le m\le n²-n+1$.

In fact I don't see why $m$ is necessary bigger than $n$. I can only prove that the determinant of a matrix in $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{Z})$ is $1$ or $-1$. Any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an estimate is not true in general. For $n=1$ we have $m=\pm 1$, and $m=-1$ is smaller than $n=1$. In general, we may take $M=-I_n$ to have $m<n$.
For $n\ge 2$ we can write down a matrix $M$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with arbitrarily large odd coefficients: take, for arbitrary $m\in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
m & m-1 \\ m+1 & m
\end{pmatrix} .
$$